# Getting " Process spawn error. Is java in the path? " error while trying to run npm run build command in root of facebook/react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, open-source, development-environment

Getting the following error message while trying to run npm run build in root folder of react project:

```
PS D:\react> npm run build

> build
> node ./scripts/rollup/build-all-release-channels.js

 BUILDING  react.development.js (umd_dev)
 COMPLETE  react.development.js (umd_dev)

 BUILDING  react.production.min.js (umd_prod)
 OH NOES!  react.production.min.js (umd_prod)

-- PLUGIN_ERROR (scripts/rollup/plugins/closure-plugin) --
-rewrite_polyfills=false --inject_libraries=false --allow_dynamic_import=true --assume_function_wrapper=false --renaming=true --js=C:\Users\callm\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-12140AroJhqjXfPIF

Process spawn error. Is java in the path?
spawn java ENOENT

    at D:\react\scripts\rollup\plugins\closure-plugin.js:16:16
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\react\node_modules\google-closure-compiler\lib\node\closure-compiler.js:107:9)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
```

I was expecting to run build command smoothly without any errors so that we can go through fixtures and can work on react library issues.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the **contribution prerequisites** [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/how-to-contribute.html#contribution-prerequisites) and make sure you installed all of them (then restart).

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install openjdk-19-jre-headless
you can use this command to solve and to upgrade to the latest version of java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).